# cran Package "party_1.0-9" windows version has issue for instruction called library(party)

Tags: r, package, rstudio, cran

Am using R Studio windows version.
I have installed cran Package "party_1.0-9" windows version (for decision tree related tasks). It showed as succesful installation.
The moment i gave the instruction library(party), it displayed following error messages

```
Loading required package: grid
Loading required package: zoo

Attaching package: ‘zoo’

The following object is masked from ‘package:base’:

    as.Date, as.Date.numeric

Error: package ‘sandwich’ required by ‘party’ could not be found
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package ‘party’ was built under R version 3.0.2 
2: package ‘zoo’ was built under R version 3.0.2 "
```

I repeatedly uninstalled and installed, the problems still remains the same. Please help.

Comment: You should do `install.packages('sandwich')`.